# how to bold the characters using echo

Tags: scripts

required output of echo in bold letters

while using echo command I want the content to be bold and it should have same bold view while appending echo output to the file

echo "hi">test.txt

i want hi should be in bold in the test.txt file

Comment: A text file is just plain text, no font-formatting such as bold or italics. You'll need to use a different file format

Comment: @ElefantPhace:CAn you let me know while echo command when i append it to a file i need to see characters in bold which format would support it.

Comment: You can't do it. Not in a plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

`.txt` is a raw text format: you can't use any type of text-formatting.

Some "generic" conventions are `**Bold**` and `*italic*` because a lot of markdown will interpret these as bold and italic.

Another thing that could be usefull to display a bold text is to use bash. But it will of course only work in you display the `.txt` in a bash-terminal. For this, you can use something like `echo -e "\033[1mThis text is bold"`, but it will be copied 'as it' in the `.txt` file.

Comment: An easier option in bash would be to use `echo $(tput bold)This is bold`

Comment: Yes the above code in terminal makes it bold but when same is appendind to a text file it shows as its is.so i want to see same bold ouput inside a file..

Comment: @ElefantPhace:the output inside file shows as [1m this is bold

Comment: Hi @ElefantPhace:its same while running the tput has same issue I am able to see characters  [1m hi inside a.txt file                                code ran is as below.                                            echo $(tput bold) hi>a.text

Comment: ".txt is a raw text format: you can't use any type of text-formatting." The first line of my answer.

Comment: @MrVaykadji:ok so which format i shoul use any help.